# Как в эхо сервер, который пересылает текст добавить пересылку файлов и картинок?

Tags: python, сервер, сокет

Написал простой эхо сервер и клиент

Сервер:

```py
import socket
import logging
import threading

HEADER = 1024
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5005
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr}')
    connected = True
    while connected:
        data = conn.recv(HEADER)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)


def start():
    server.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTRED] {threading.activeCount() -1 }')

start()
```

Клиент:

```py
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5005


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print('Client connected.')
while True:
    user_input = str(input())
    if not user_input:
        break
    s.sendall(user_input.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print("Data received")
```

Как сделать так, что бы можно было принимать (до этого отправлять их с клиента) кроме текста еще файлы и картинки и отправлять их обратно на клиент? Ведь нас на сторону сервера поступают байты. Как определить что это именно файл, а не текст, когда ему приходят байты.
Помогите с написанием кода.

Answer (score 0):

я когда передавал изображение я его переделывал в байты

```
import os, base64, io, PIL
user_input = str(input())
if user_input.startswith('C:\\'): #если  user_input это какой то путь
    if os.path.isfile(user_input): #если  user_input это действительная картинка  
        data = base64.b64encode(open(user_input, 'rb').read()) #картинка  в байты
        s.sendall(bytes(data))
```

из байтов в картинку

```
Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(server.recv(4096).decode()))).save('ваш путь для сохранения')
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, пожалуйста. Сервер должен принимать текст или картинки и отправлять обратно в зависимости от того, что пришло (или просто текст или картинку). А есть приходят байты, то как сервер должен понять что именно приходит

Comment: @АлександрАлексеев вы можете создать функцию в которой будут передаваться только картинки, указываете путь к картинке, оно переделывает в байты и отправит , сервер или клиент приймут картинку (можете например в цикл  бесконечный поставить расшифровку и оно будет расшифровывать и  сохранять всегда когда приходит новая дата )  вот еще вопрос можете посмотреть может поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196123/python-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-socket